# Best remote desktop tool(other than teamviewer)

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop

what is the best remote desktop tool for controlling a remote pc with ubuntu?

I am using TeamViewer and it keeps crashing all the time, I can't stand it anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have full access to the network the PC is on...meaning can you forward ports?  Or do you require a 3rd party site to access it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to determine if you absolutely need a third party service like TeamViewer which requires that both your Ubuntu computer and your remote computer connect to a third party (Team Viewer) to operate.  If have a simple home network and have control of your own router, you likely don't need a third party.

Without a third party, whichever software you choose, you will need to open ports on your firewall and/or router to access that software.  I recommend only exposing SSH ports and using [SSH Tunnels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237904/what-does-port-forwarding-mean-in-ssh-port-forwarding) to access the remote desktop to minimize the number of open ports/applications exposed to the internet.  You will also need to keep track of your IP address, either manually, or by setting up Dynamic DNS.

As far as specific software solutions, VNC has been around a while and there are many flavors of it.  However you need to configure it to share your existing desktop vs creating a whole new one.  There is tightvncserver and tigervnc-standalone-server available via apt-get. This requires forwarding or tunneling port 5900 (or 5901 depending on how you configure it).  Client side, there are several VNC Viewer apps for all OS, including mobile.

I particularly like NoMachine.  Setup is easy server side, download the deb file from [www.nomachine.com](http://www.nomachine.com), install with `sudo dpkg -i nomachine_X.X.X_X_amd64.deb`, then start with `sudo service nxserver start`.  This requires forwarding or tunneling port 4000.  For the client side, they also have an installer for all major OS both mobile and desktop.

Comment: You are on the right path. You only need to make it clearer. Moreover, if both client and server are behind a NAT router or a firewall some other things need to be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Try google's AnyDesk
Pretty much the same thing with different software
There is always VNC as well....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit  your question  to expand it with specific details about what you do.